# How can I check the Field.choices value is unique in same model django

Tags: django

I need that user can select only one photo with value 'COVER' in `photo_tipo`.

**Part of Models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
...

class Photo(models.Model):
    PHOTO_TIPO_CHOICES = (
            ('GALLERIA', 'Galleria'),
            ('COVER', 'Cover'),
            ('PLANIMETRIA', 'Planimetria'),
    )

    photo_tipo = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=PHOTO_TIPO_CHOICES,
        verbose_name='Tipo immagine',
        default='GALLERIA',
    )

    listing = models.ForeignKey(
        Listing, 
        related_name='photos',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

**Part of Admin.py**

```
class PhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Photo
    readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)


@admin.register(models.Listing)
class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PhotoInline,
    ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpblY.png)

Can I control user selection with error message, or remove 'COVER' from selection list if he have already chosen COVER photo?
I can't use `unique=True` in field because all model must have COVER photo.

Comment: The user is using the admin to add it? You shouldnt be doing that. Make a form and only allow 1 thing to be added/picked and that should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes user using admin to add it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I think you'll need to implement a model form for your listing admin. I'm not sure that wil work with an inline, but that would be something like this:

```
class ListingAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_photos(self):
        photos = self.cleaned_data['photos']
        cover_photos = [
            photo for photo in photos if photo.photo_tipo == 'COVER'
        ]
        if len(cover_photos) > 1:
            self.add_error('photos', forms.ValidationError('Cannot add more than one cover photo', code='more_than_one_cover'))
        return photos


@admin.register(Listing)
class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PhotoInline,
    ]
    form = ListingAdminForm
```

If that doesn't work, you could create custom fields on the form, one field for the cover photo, that allow only one & another field for the others type of photos. Then you'd have to do some validation.

## Alternative approach

Often, when I find myself doing too much work in the admin it's because I didn't design my models as I should have.

Have you considered encoding the cardinality in the models?

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField()


class Listing(models.Model):
    # Restricted to 1 cover photo by the model, add null=False if required
    cover_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Multiple photos for gallery allowed
    gallery_photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo)
```

Would it make your admin code a lot simpler?

Comment: Thank you Bruno i' ll  try all your suggestions.